# Errors when trying to install Ubuntu: ata1 softreset failed

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I'm currently running Windows 7 on my PC and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04. 
I have already done the whole 'volume shrink' on my drive and allocated 30 GB.

After making the necessary changes to BIOS to boot from my usb,
I can go through to the page where the computer asks for how I want to run Ubuntu - for now I want to try run without installing and then later I will have dual boot. Immediately afterwards, I get a grey screen and then:

```
[10.632268] ata1: softreset failed (device not ready)
[10/632341] ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
[13.009722] sd 4:0:0:0 [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[13.009777] sd 4:0:0:0 [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

Once the screen goes through this, I end up with a black screen with some colours in the top left corner and some random symbols.

Currently, using this website for installation process: https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Dual-boot-Linux-and-Windows-on-a-PC-with-W/

Have tried here for resolving issue but no luck: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1052987&page=4&p=7580180#post7580180

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you install? I hope you didn't pick 12.0 as shown in your tutorial. If you did, retry it with 18.04 LTS first.

Comment: @Panki I tried 18.04.4 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it was an issue with my graphics card. Using a nvidia graphics card and the drivers didn't work properly. Used nomodeset and turned off quicksplash in setup to work :)

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are
better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).